# T is an isomorphism if and only if T* is an isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space. Let $T \in L(H)$, i.e. $T$ is a linear continuous operator on $H$. Prove that if $T$ is an isomorphism, then $T^*$ is an isomorphism.

I have proved that $\ker T^{*}$ = $(\text{range}(T))^{\perp} = \{0\}$, and $(\text{range}(T^{*}))^{\perp} = \ker((T^{*})^*) = \ker T = \{0\}$

But I don't know how to prove $\text{range}(T^{*})$ is closed. Can someone help me with this? Or is there a better way to prove the statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not saying you're approach won't work, but there is an easier way.  If $T$ is an isomorphism, it has an inverse $T^{-1}$.  Show that $(T^{-1})^*$ is the inverse of $T^*$.

Comment: You're welcome.  Glad to help!

Comment: @Aweygan If I understand well the objective of the OP, the main topic is to prove that $T^*$ is a continuous operator. And I don’t make a direct link between your answer and the continuity of $T^*$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net That $T^*$ is continuous is a separate matter entirely.  Showing that $T^*$ is an isomorphism amounts to showing that it is a bijection.